# Registry key / value keeps getting recreated

Tags: vb.net

I have a program which deletes specific registry values in the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Compatibility Assistant\Store` key.

The code to delete those registry values is located in `FormClosed` but the values gets recreated a couple of seconds after the program closes.

If you know how to fix this, it would be great if you could tell me!

Here is my code:

```
Dim key As Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey
Dim keypath As String = "Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Compatibility Assistant\Store"

key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(keypath, True)

If key.GetValue("value here") Is Nothing Then

Else
    key.DeleteValue("value here")
End If
```

Comment: Why you need to delete this entry? It seems a default windows service (Program Compatibility Assistant) to check for compatibility of existing software.

Comment: On an unrelated note, your `If...Else` block is a bit ridiculous. If you don't want to do anything when `GetValue` returns `Nothing` then don't test for it. Move the code from the `Else` block to the `If` block, get rid of the `Else` and change `Is` to `IsNot`.

Comment: I was also wondering why the entry gets created after running an app and came to the assumption that it might be PCA doing its thing. But when the app gets uninstalled, the entry remains. I checked this against Windows ADK's Application Compatibility Toolkit's Standard User Analyzer but it didn't find any issue. Strangely, after uninstalling Windows ADK, it too had its own entry left in the same registry key, so I posted [a question in Windows Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1183873/why-is-there-a-registry-value-created-in-hkcu-appc) to get an explanation.